# OData Protocol version

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, odata

I've a WCF service and an MVC4 application that communicates via OData protocol. But I've the following issue : The version of the protocol must be at least version 3 to handle collection type. How (and where) to change the version of the OData protocol used ?

Just to be clear, here is my MVC4 application part that generates the error :

```
String serviceAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WCFADDRESS"];
            DataServiceContext context = new DataServiceContext(new Uri(serviceAddress));
            List<Result> prod = context.Execute<Result>(new Uri(serviceAddress + "sp2?cid="+clientID), "GET", false).ToList();
```

At the third line i've the error.
I've checked the version of OData Reference in WCF service and MVC app : 5.5 and 5.0... How to solve that ?
Thanks !

For the french speackers, here is the exact error :
 Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataException: Les types de collection sont uniquement pris en charge dans la version 3.0 du protocole OData et les versions ultérieures. Il n'est pas pris en charge dans la version 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

The version of the WCF Data Services (5.5) is independent from the version of the protocol being used. You can have a 5.5 server that only supports up to OData v2, for example.  The latest version of OData is version 3, with version 4 coming out soon.

If you're using WCF Data Services as the framework for your OData server, you can set the max protocol version with the MaxProtocolVersion configuration property:

```
// This method is called only once to initialize service-wide policies.
public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
{
    // .. Other configuration goes here ...

    // Set the max protocol version of the server to be v3
    config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion =
        System.Data.Services.Common.DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;
}
```

(The `InitializeService()` method should be in your data service class, which derives from `DataService<T>`)